# ¿Cómo puedo refrescar Apache TomCat 8 de forma Automática?

Tags: java-ee, tomcat

Tengo el siguiente código que me permite recibir imágenes de un cliente y guardarlas en el servidor.

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    //  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Se ha recibido una solicitud"+request.getContentLength());
    Part p=request.getPart("userfile");
    Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
    String id=c.get(Calendar.YEAR)+""+c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+""+c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+""
    +c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+""+c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    String fileName = "IMG-"+id;
InputStream fileContent = p.getInputStream();
InputStreamAFile(fileContent,fileName);

}
```

El método funciona bien pero el problema es que si después quiero acceder a la imagen desde un URL me dice que el recurso no está disponible.
Para poder ver la imagen mediante un URL tengo que refrescar la aplicación o reiniciar el servidor pero de forma manual, pero obviamente esto no es algo útil si deseo ver reflejados los resultados después de insertar la imagen.


Mis imagenes las estoy guardando en el siguiente directorio:

```
../TDIDP/WebContent/imagenes
```

Por lo que la url de la imagen queda de la siguiente forma:

```
http://mi_ip:8080/TDIDP/imagenes/IMG-23432432
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El **DefaultServlet**  de tomcat por dafault está configurado para no listar o mostrar un directorio. Si deseas cambiar está configuración ve a donde tienes instalado tu tomcat en:  .**/conf/web.xml** , ahí buscar "servlet" y cambia el parámetro "listings"  a true. Ejemplo:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>listings</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

valor ya cambiado:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>listings</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Cómo quedaría finalmente.Ojo, tome como referencia la versión 8:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```